# Error 2501 MS Access runMacro

Tags: ms-access, macros, vb6, vba

I must say there is a ghost in my machine as no one else is having this issue. I'm trying to run a report from my VB6 application and on Acc.docmd.RunMacro "Macro" I get error 2501 "operation was canceled." The strangest thing is that it works on my coworkers computers, i'm the only one with this issue. The code definitely works, I am able to run the macro in question in MS Access, I have "Enable all macros" in Trust Center options. What else can I try to make this devil work?

Comment: Please show the routines in the macro- opening reports? Running queries?

Comment: @parfait - running queries, appending data to table. It runs perfectly fine in access and from every other computer but mine. I'm think it has to do with an option or something because everything else is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the issue was I did not have the latest update for Office 2007 (which is SP3). Once i downloaded it everything ran fine.